# Access join table fields in Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm, join

Here is my (simplified) Category entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{    
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    protected $parent = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent", fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="category_tree",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="child_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $children;
}
```

Can i write a DQL query which would give me a result with, for each category:

- its id
- an array with the ids of its children

In SQL it's pretty simple of course, but join tables seem transparent in Doctrine.

Comment: This does not work this way in DQL. In DQL, you can eventually fetch-join associated items as of http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Comment: Yes i'm already doing fetch-join, but as i need to get only ids of a join table along with the main table, it's a big overhead that i was willing to spare. I'll keep using fetch joins then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need references, there's a handy getReference() method, use like this:

```
$item = $this->em->getReference('Entity\Item', $id);
```

Alternatively, you could set the associated entities to EXTRA_LAZY. It all depends on what exactly you need, but those are two approaches to reduce overhead.